# Get difference of two numbers which are in two rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table `parameters_info`.

```
name                     | value
---------------------------------
fee for normal scan      |20
fee for especial scan    |500
```

I want to get the value (fee for especial scan - fee for normal scan) which is 480;

How do I achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: What if there are more rows ? Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: PS: not my Downvote; but question is definitely not clear.

Comment: What's the criterion for the 2 rows to match?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Some people downvote without indicating why... BTW: not my downvote either

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @RobertKock I have a table called params. I store params as records. I want to get the difference between two params. End of the day I want to pass `fee for normal scan` and `fee for especial scan` get the difference value 500-20 = 480

Comment: So the names are fixed `fee for normal scan` and `fee for especial scan` or are there other possible names?

Comment: @RobertKock salman A answer is what I exactly looked for. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
SELECT (SELECT value FROM t WHERE name = 'fee for especial scan') - 
       (SELECT value FROM t WHERE name = 'fee for normal scan')
```

Comment: Wow! Dead simple. =) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation using [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function. It *may be more efficient* than using multiple Uncorrelated subqueries:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE name 
                WHEN 'fee for especial scan' THEN value
                WHEN 'fee for normal scan' THEN -1*value
                ELSE 0
           END)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I marked the answer. It was a simple query.